# Spring JPA method to find entities with beforeAndEqual a date AND afterAndEqual a date

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I have an entity Tournament as follows:

```
class Tournament {
    //other attributes
    private LocalDate startDate;
    private LocalDate endDate;
}
```

This represents a tournament that runs for few days/months, from startDate to enddate. 
I need to retrieve all Tournaments that run today, at this moment, somthing like **startDate <= today && endDate >= today**, using Spring JPA and paging.

The closest I found was following:

```
@Repository
public interface TournamentRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Tournament, Long> {

    Page<Tournament> findByStartBeforeAndEndAfter(LocalDate date, LocalDate dateCopy, Pageable page); //today's date is passed as date and dateCopy

}
```

Method call:

```
tournamentRepository.findByStartBeforeAndEndAfter(LocalDate.now(), LocalDate.now(), page);
```

This can be interpreted as **startDate < today && endDate > today**, so it doesn't work if a tournament runs today and only for 1 day.

Is there a better way to do this using Spring JPA without having to write a custom query?

Comment: Have you tried `findByStartDateLessThanEqualAndEndDateGreaterThanEqual`? The [official documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation) clarifies that `LessThanEqual` and `GreaterThanEqual` are supported keywords.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`CURRENT_DATE`](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/date#Current_Date_and_Time_), [`CURRENT_TIME`](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/date#Current_Date_and_Time_), [`CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/date#Current_Date_and_Time_) are predefined functions in JPA. You can use that.

Try this

```
@Repository
public interface TournamentRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Tournament, Long> {

    @Query("Select t from Tournament t where t.startDate <= CURRENT_DATE and t.endDate >= CURRENT_DATE")
    Page<Tournament> findByStartBeforeAndEndAfter(Pageable page);

}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use LessThan, GreaterThan, LessThanEqual, GreaterThanEqual with dates.

```
@Repository
public interface TournamentRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Tournament, Long> {

    Page<Tournament> findByGreaterThanEqualStartDateAndLessThanEqualEndDate(LocalDate date, LocalDate dateCopy, Pageable page); //today's date is passed as date and dateCopy

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `@Query` annotation and write his own query like below code.

```
@Repository
    public interface TournamentRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Tournament, Long> {
        @Query("select t from Tournament t where t.startDate <=:date and t.endDate >=: dateCopy")
        Page<Tournament> findByStartBeforeAndEndAfter(@Param("date")LocalDate date,@Param("dateCopy") LocalDate dateCopy, Pageable page); //today's date is passed as date and dateCopy

    }
```

You can also try `native query` like this

```
@Repository
public interface TournamentRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Tournament, Long> {
    @Query("select * from tournament where start_date <=:date and end_date >=: dateCopy",nativeQuery=true)
    List<Tournament> findByStartBeforeAndEndAfter(@Param("date")LocalDate date,@Param("dateCopy") LocalDate dateCopy); //today's date is passed as date and dateCopy

}
```

Comment: See this gits https://github.com/nikiforov-alexander/spring-data-rest-find-by-date-example/blob/master/src/main/java/com/example/dao/UserHistoryDao.java

It seems like you can specify a specific format